# How can I run the exact same function several times with different inputs and do so simultaniously

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, simultaneous

I have a lot of data to process (around 30-60 million data sets) and I need to process it in equal quarters each quarter with different settings. So I made myself a function that calls a few other functions I had previously written. I then call said function 4 times with the different inputs and get out a bunch of plots and have it write a bunch of numbers to files. Everything works great but it takes a few minutes to run through and I am an impatient lad. Especially since I get new data sets everyday, sometimes a few times a day. I am not by any means a programmer or very versed in any coding language, but I see no reason why I cant simply run each function call simultaneously to save time. I don't really care how these run simultaneously just as long as it significantly speeds things up for me haha.

I tried to fun multiple threads but that just gave me weird plots almost like the threads were communicating between themselves and mixing up the outputs. then I tried running multiple processes like in the code but it seemed like they just ran sequentially anyways.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def func1(x):
  return (x)



if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = Process(target=func1,(1,))
  p1.start()
  p2 = Process(target=func1,(2,))
  p2.start()
  p1.join()
  p2.join()
```

Thanks for any help you can offer

Comment: why do you thing they mix data? are they read data from the same file or write data to the same file. Or maybe they use the same connection to database ? This is the only reason to use the same data. Every process may need to write in own files and later read from these files.

Comment: Multithreading won't work unless the bottleneck is I/O anyway. Does each call need to read a lot of data from an external sources (files on disk, a database, a website)? [This intro to concurrency](https://youtu.be/Bv25Dwe84g0) would be a good place to start for you.

Comment: furas, the reason I think they were mixing data was because my plots, when ran normally, consist of one polynomial curve fit over the data. But when I attempted to run them simultaneously with multiple threads I would get some plots with no curve fit and others with more than one curve fit (the second fit from another plot which could only be generated in another function call with different settings). It would also print several of the same plot when it should only print one. Each call reads and writes data from/to a different set of files.

Comment: jpmc26, Yes all the data is being read from many different .lvm files. All the files are stored on disk (ssd). I will watch that video, thank you.